# Global maxima and minima of $f(x)=(e^x+e^{-x})/2$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

This question is from my textbook, and I am having trouble solving this.
I am asked to find the global maxima and minima of the function $$f(x)= \frac{e^x+e^{-x}}{2}$$ for $x \in [-\ln(2),\ln(7)]$
My attempt: $$f'(x)=\frac{e^x-e^{-x}}{2}$$
Then I equated the equation to $0$, which gives
$$e^x-e^{-x}=0$$
$$\implies t^2-1=0, t=e^x$$
$$\implies t= +1 /-1$$
$$e^x=+1 \implies x=0, e^{-x}=-1 \implies x \notin \mathbb{R}$$
This question was a MCQ type, so I did not bother finding out the curvature since the options would help me judge which one is the maxima or the minima, but here only one valid solution comes up, which is the minima according to the options, but how do we calculate the maxima?
Even though I dont think the use of higher mathematics(above than high school level) will be required, but still I would appreciate solutions, using basic calculus taught at the high school level. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: $f(x)=\cosh(x)$

Comment: @DARK I did thought of substituting it as $\cosh(x)$, but I would like a solution without using that property, since it's not taught in the book.

Comment: Note that $f(x)=f(-x)$ follows it symmetric about $Y$ axis and $f(x)\geq1$ equality occurs at $x=0$

Comment: If you use interval testing on the derivative, you will see the end behavior of the function approach $\infty$ as $x\to\pm\infty$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now that you know $f’(x)$ has a real root which is $x=0$, you can use it to draw the sign scheme of $f’(x)$. More specifically, $f’(x)>0$ is when $x>0$ and $f’(x)<0$ is when $x<0$. This means $f(x)$ is a monotone increasing function on $(0,\infty)$ and monotone decreasing on $(-\infty,0)$. This means that in the given interval of $x$, the minimum can occur at $x=0$, and maximum either at $x=\ln(7)$ or $x=-\ln(2)$. Checking both these possibilities we conclude that $$\min_{x=0} f(x)=1$$ $$\max_{x=\ln 7} f(x)=\frac{25}{7}$$

Comment: @bobby76: I would focus primarily on being able to quickly and accurately access rough global qualitative aspects of a graph using the first derivative test, which Sahaj has done (some examples explained in detail are given in my 29 October 2006 sci.math post [Sign charts and the first derivative test](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/TpC_fn-MkU4/m/QW0IXAWhqf4J)), and only later worry about various test-specific shortcuts and tricks such as one might use in a multiple choice test. By the way, google's ill-chosen switch away from fixed font format totally messed up my sign charts there!

Comment: While this is true, there is no need to determine if $x=0$ corresponds to a local min or max. Since we have a continuous function on a closed interval, we simply need to find the $y$-values of the endpoints and critical points and determine the max/min based off those values.

Comment: @Bonnaduck: I didn't even notice that the original question was for a closed and bounded interval. Given this assumption, the first derivative test is not needed and there is a standard method for such problems -- compute the value of the function where the derivative is zero, and where the derivative is undefined, and at the endpoints. For what it's worth, near the end of [this Academia SE answer](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/69266/49593) describes how I used to pose such questions on tests.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro yes you are right, I am having trouble understanding the sign charts due to the font.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Yes that is a better way, I'll keep that in mind for the upcoming questions!

Answer (score 1):

With some algebbra,

$y=\frac{e^x +e^{-x}}{2}$

$2ye^x=e^{2x}+1$

$e^{2x}-2ye^{x}+1=0$

$e^x=\frac{2y \pm \sqrt{4y^2-4}}{2}=y \pm \sqrt{y^2-1}$

So $y^2\ge 1$ else the radical is imaginary. But $y$ is the sum of powers of $e$ which are always positive, so $y\ge 1$.

So the smallest possible candidate for $y$ is 1 and plugging that into $y$ gives you $e^{x}=1\implies x=0$ which is on the interval in question .

---

Note the derivative is always positive if $x>0$ and negative for $x<0$. So the above minimum is a global minimum and we can expect the maxima to occur at the endpoints of the interval. So

$f(\ln 7)= 25/7$ and $f(-\ln2)=5/8$

$25/7>5/8$, so the max is $25/7$ though there are higher values outside the interval.

Answer (score 1):

By $AM-GM$ inequality $$f(x)=\frac{e^x+e^{-x}}2\geq\sqrt{e^xe^{-x}}=1$$
and equality occurs iff $e^x=e^{-x}$, that is $x=0$.

For global maximum on $[-\ln2,\ln7]$, it is enough to consider the interval $[0,\ln7]$ since the function is even.

If $x_1>x_2\geq0$, then $e^{x_1}-e^{x_2}>0$ and $e^{x_1}e^{x_2}>1.$ These imply $f(x_1)>f(x_2)$. Hence $f(x)$ is an increasing function on $[0,\ln7]$, with global maximum $f(\ln7)=\frac{25}7.$